# Настроить "Add Selection To Next Find Match" в PHPStorm как в VSCode (VSCodium)?

Tags: phpstorm, visual-studio-code, vscodium

В **VSCode(VSCodium)** есть команда `Add Selection To Next Find Match(выделить следующее совпадение)` и работает она на сочетание клавиш <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>+</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>. Как называется аналогичная функция в **PHPStorm** и как перенастроить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В **PHPStorm** данная функция называется `Add Selection For Next Occurrence` и работает на сочетание клавиш <kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>+</kbd><kbd>J</kbd>.

Чтобы чтобы настроить данную функцию как **VSCode(VSCodium)** необходимо перейти в `Settings->Keymap`. Далее в поиске справа написать *Add Selection For Next Occurrence* и кликнуть два раза по искомой функции. Далее удаляем текущую комбинацию (`Remove Alt+J`). Опять кликаем два раза и выбираем пункт `Add Keyboard Shortcut`(Добавить сочетание клавиш), затем нажимаем <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>+</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> и сохраняем.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

> Если вы ранее не настраивали сочетание клавиш, то вам **PHPStorm** скажет, что данная комбинация уже используется. Если вы согласны на изменение, то нажимайте кнопку `Remove`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Официальная [документация](https://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2014/03/working-with-multiple-selection-in-phpstorm-8-eap/).